# Xcode: UTF-8 characters in sqlite database not displaying

Tags: python, xcode, utf-8, sqlite

I need to display text in a UITableViewCell that has unicode characters; however, all it seems to display is the actual string containing the unicode string embedded in it. (example: my UITableViewCell textLabel displays 'Cari\u00F1na' instead of 'Cariña'

I create a sqlite3 database by parsing a utf-8 text file with the following python script:

```
import sqlite3;
import csv;

conn = sqlite3.connect('varietals.sqlite3')
#conn.text_factory = str
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('drop table if exists varietals')
c.execute('create table varietals(id integer primary key autoincrement, name VARCHAR, type VARCHAR)')


data = open("varietals.txt", "rU").readlines()
for row in data:
    vals = row.split(',')
    name = unicode(vals[0])
    t = unicode(vals[1])
    sql = "insert into varietals values(NULL,?,?)"
    c.execute(sql, [name, t])

conn.commit()
```

In XCode, I'm parsing the database using a standard sqlite3 script

```
 NSString *query = @"SELECT * FROM varietals ORDER BY type DESC";
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, [query UTF8String], -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK){

    while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW){

      //  int uniqueId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        char *nameChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *typeChars = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);

        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:nameChars];
        NSString *type = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:typeChars];


        NSDictionary *varietal = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:name, @"name", type, @"type", nil];
        [retval addObject:varietal];

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get the textLabel to display 'name' (Cariña) correctly, it just keeps displaying 'Cari\u00F1na'; however, if I hardcode in the 'cellForRowAtIndexPath' method: cell.textLabel.text = @"Cari\u00F1na"; It DOES display correctly. I just cannot get it to work from the database file.

Is there something I'm missing in my python script? Sqlite Parser?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What does your text file `varietals.txt` look like when you look at its raw bytes, e.g. `hexdump -C varietals.txt`?

Comment: Open the database using the command line `sqlite3` command and select the values from the table and see what they look like.